# Does IIS APP Pool identity account require internet access

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server

Currently we have an ASP.NET website hosted on IIS 7 . We use an user account (created on Active Directory) as Identity for APP pool . Website is accessed by both internet and intranet users. Till now the user account which is being used as identity in APP pool has internet access but in coming days this user account will not have internet access ( Internet access will be blocked for this user account as per organization policy) .Can some body let me know whether this will affect the website in any way? Will the external users still be able to access the site if we continue to use the same user account as identity  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we're going to say "no, that'll work just fine" and it doesn't, who are you going to blame? It is your responsibility to test this with a machine and a user that don't affect your production environment.

However, no, your application pool identity generally doesn't need internet access. The only reason to need internet access for your application pool identity, is when one application running on that pool needs internet access. For example API calls, downloading images, or whatever.

Comment: Yes thats what I was trying to do for past 4 days; to disable the internet access to the identity account and test it. Since I dont have access rights to do it and the person (server administrator) who has rights to do it, it takes ages for him to reply and you know how internal organization ticketing policy works.My ticket is on the queue and it hops between different departments and Iam damn sure they will take ample time to understand my requirement from developers point of view. This was the reason I posted it on stack overflow :).Any ways thanks for the answer.I will test it.

Comment: you were right, after revoking internet access to service account the site works well except for the part where it is trying to access the internet .

Answer (score 0):

i think the user account on which your app pool is running is on your server and it has nothing to do with user's internet connection.

as far as user account present in your server you can access your site without any issue.

Comment: thanks for your answer . I guess you got it wrong . I meant whether removing internet access to App pool Identity account will affect website's functionality and not the users internet access.

Comment: oh sorry, no i think application pool identity is not dependent on internet connection.